# Syntax Error in Pattern Matching on Algebraic Data Type

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

```
data BoolLit = T | F
instance Eq BoolLit where
   b1 == b2 = True

data BExp = BoolLit |
            Or BExp BExp

bEval :: BExp -> BoolLit
bEval T = T
```

I'm getting the following syntax error:

```
Couldn't match expected type 'BExp' with actual type 'BoolLit'   
In the pattern: T   
In an equation for 'bEval': bEval T = T
```

The data declaration has declared that BoolLit is a BExp.
So, I don't understand why Haskell is giving an error.
I'd like to know why and how to correct it.
Thanks.

Comment: That's a type error, not a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared the type `BoolLit` with constructors `T :: BoolLit` and `F :: BoolLit`, and you have also declared the type `BExp` with constructors `BoolLit :: BExp` and `Or :: BExp -> BExp -> BExp`.  If you want to wrap the `BoolLit` type, you'll need to express that in `BExp`'s constructors:

```
data BExp = BoolLit BoolLit | Or BExpr BExpr
```

Then you can write `bEval` as

```
bEval (BoolLit T) = T
```

Also note that you've defined your `Eq` instance to always return `T`, no matter what the arguments to `==` are.  You need to pattern match here:

```
instance Eq BoolLit where
    T == T = True
    F == F = True
    _ == _ = False
```

Alternatively you can let GHC figure it out for you using `deriving`:

```
data BoolLit = T | F deriving (Eq)
```

Comment: Your answer is the the same as the book I got the code from. I didn't understand why the book used BoolLit BoolLit instead of just BoolLit. I've got it now. Thanks.